# using argparse in a python script

Tags: python, argparse

I have some input file in a directory and want to make a python script with 2 functions and run the script for all of the input files in the same directory. 
the script that I made still does not work. there are 2 functions. the first one is the one which takes the input files and returns the output files. if I run this function on every single input file, it will work perfectly. so there is no problem with the function "convert".
the 2nd function in main function which is made for `"argparse"`. the script has problem in this function.

```
import argparse
import pytools

def convert(infile, outfile):
        x = pytools.split(infile)
        x.coverage(bh=True, split=True)\
         .saveas(outfile, type='bh')
        print "done"
        return


def main():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--infile", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    input = args.infile
    output = convert(args.infile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my problem is that, I do not know if introducing the input files and call for output files is done in a correct way or not. in fact I think the problem of this script is in this part:

```
input = args.infile
output = convert(args.infile)
```

do you know how to fix the script?

this is the problem I get after running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bam2bg.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "bam2bg.py", line 35, in main
    input = args.infile
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'infile'
```

Comment: Your `convert` function takes two arguments, but you're only giving it one. Use `convert(args.infile, args.outfile)`. Also, it would help if you included the error message in the question.

Comment: `x = pytools.split(infile)` what is happening in this line ? pytools has no attribute `.split` ?

Comment: I don't see how that code could produce the error you claim; there is nothing that could change the value of `args` to remove the `infile` attribute, which it does indeed have.

Comment: Do a `print(args)` right after the `parse_args`.  That helps you verify that the parser does what you want.